# Reinstalling Anaconda: import old environments

Tags: python, anaconda

I had to reinstall Anaconda due to the Issue with macOS Catalina: [how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2/Xcode_11.2.xip)

How can I import my old environments to the newly installed Anaconda-Navigator? (I have not uninstalled the old Anaconda yet)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Anaconda has previously by default been installed in the root directory folder `/anaconda3/`. Catalina no longer accepts root directory folders like this. During Catalina's installation, it moved the Anaconda folder to `/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Security/anaconda3`. The old virtual environments are still there, under the `/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Security/anaconda3/envs/` folder.

[The Anaconda Team says](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update) that this problem is not that easy to fix, and suggest two approaches: Either reinstall Anaconda, or try to repair the installation. You can find their repair instructions in that link.

If you reinstall, as I did, then there is still no simple way to restore your old environments. While Anaconda has nice functionality to export environments so that you can restore them elsewhere, this functionality requires that you can activate the environment that you want to export — which we can't do here for the old installation moved to the `Relocated Items` folder. Still, I found a way to make it work.

If you go into the `.../anaconda3/envs/` folder of your old installation, you can see all of your old environments. If you simply copy one of them into the the new installation at `/Users/your_user/opt/anaconda3/envs/`, you will be able to activate it in the terminal as

```
conda activate your_env
```

This doesn't mean that you can really use these environments. Something as simple as trying to start the Python interpreter will fail, as it's no longer installed where the environment expects it to be. However, you can now export the environment as

```
conda env export > your_env.yml
```

This will let you reinstall the environment in the new Anaconda installation so that it matches the environment in the old installation. You can do this by removing the environment and creating it afresh from the `your_env.yml` file you just exported:

```
conda deactivate
conda remove -n your_env --all
conda env create -f your_env.yml
```

If everything works correctly, this should make your old environment available again. You then just need to do the same thing for every environment that you want to restore.

Comment: Can I copy an env folder to a new anaconda3 directory, if it has exactly the same directory path as the old one? I renamed my old ~/anaconda3 to ~/anaconda3bk and installed ~/anaconda3. Now, can I simply move ~/anaconda3bk/envs/my_env to ~/anaconda3/envs/my_env and expect it to work as before?

Comment: @JordanHe: In my case it did not work, but in your specific case I think it might. When you move the Anaconda folder and create a new one where it used to be, there will still be Python binaries in place where the old environment expects them to be.