# Import conda enviroments from a previous install

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I have updated my computer from Windows 7 to Windows 10 on a SSD. I have a HDD with all my data  with my old Anaconda installation with five environments.

I have had to install again Anaconda and I try to install over the old Anaconda folder (with the enviroments), but the installer doesn't allow me to do it.

I have tried to import the environments from the old installation but I don't know how to do it because I don't have a yaml file.

How can I import the environments from the previous installation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reinstalling Anaconda: import old environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780651/reinstalling-anaconda-import-old-environments)

Comment: @user_na Yes, it works but I can recreate the environment due to this error: "ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - tensorflow-addons==0.9.1=py37_1
  - typeguard==2.7.0=py37_0
  - onnx==1.7.0=py37_0"